# Databound DropDownList default option always returns 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, selectedindex

I am creating a form to upload images. I have a dropdownlist fed by a SQL database, which contains the name and Id of previously created albums that the user may upload images into. If I select the second or lower option in the dropdownlist it always returns the correct Id, but if I leave the default option selected it always returns 0.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here!

On page load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["userId"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            BindDropDownList();
        }
    }
```

BindDropDownList method:

```
    string qry2 = "SELECT Id, albumName FROM albums WHERE albumOwnerId=@albOwnId";

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(qry2, conn);

    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@albOwnId", Session["userId"]);

    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);

    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

    da2.Fill(dt2);

    album.DataValueField = "Id";
    album.DataTextField = "albumName";

    album.DataSource = dt2;
    album.DataBind();

    album.SelectedItem.Value = dt2.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString();
    albumData = Int32.Parse(album.SelectedItem.Value);

    conn.Close();
}
```

Selected Index Changed Method:

```
     protected void album_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList album = Page.FindControl("album") as DropDownList;

    albumData = Int32.Parse(album.SelectedItem.Value);
}
```

ASP.net:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="album" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="album_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList><br />
```

Comment: How do send teh selected item to the server? Is there a button? I ask this because I don't see AutopPostback = "true" in the dropdownlist and I 'm trying to reproduce the problem

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The variable 'albumData' is passed on click of an upload button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the discussion, I think the problem is that you handle the OnSelectedIndexChanged event and not the OnClick event of the button.

If you don't change the value of the dropdownlist the OnSelectedIndexChanged will not be raised.

You should handle the button OnClick event:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClick="btn_Click" />

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList album = Page.FindControl("album") as DropDownList;

    albumData = Int32.Parse(album.SelectedItem.Value);
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks! I had a feeling this was roughly what I needed to do but didn't understand how to implement it. I have removed my SelectedIndexChanged method altogether and added this to my upload button on click.

Thanks again!

Comment: Good, I see you have another question pending, do you still need an answer there too?

Comment: That's very much a work in progress, I'll see how it goes :). Thanks again!